# Aharonov-Bohm effect possibilities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, aharonov-bohm

1. Could Aharonov-Bohm effect, in principle, be used to transfer either power or data? Aka wireless power transfer?
2. What limits the distance between a moving particle and the solenoid on which A-B effect manifests itself? Shouldn't this distance, in principle, be infinite, as no classical fields are involved? What could be done to make it infinite?
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect

Comment: Although there is no classical field, there is a classical potential and this is non-zero.

Comment: If strength of magnetic field falls proportionally to the distance from a magnet, then what about the strength of potential? Does it depend on distance? In my understanding it is still a quantum phenomenon?

Comment: The potential will depend upon distance and yes, you're right - it is seen as a quantum phenomenon. The potentials influence the phase of the quantum wave and we get interference showing the presence of the potential.

Comment: Which physics law governs falling potential strength with distance? Could you give me a link? I think it is not the same as voltage potential between two electrodes?

Comment: I can't think of a reference off-hand. You can try Wikipedias article on the Ahronov-Bohm effect. They give a formula for the phase shift for a particle following two paths with the same start and endpoint. The phase shift is related to tge magnetic flux in the area between the two paths.

Comment: Is there any effect similar to A-B effect, but which manifests itself on much larger distances between interacting component?

Comment: I don't know. However, interestingly there a gravitational analogue of the Aharonov-Bohm effect that has been discovered. Look it up on Physics World.

Answer (score 0):

> Could Aharonov-Bohm effect, in principle, be used to transfer either power or data?

Usually, the Aharonov-Bohm consist of a current of electrons going from one place to the other. The current will be suppressed at specific values of the magnetic field. So yes, in principle it can be used to digitally transfer information (0/1 when current is on/off ).

> Aka wireless power transfer?

I would not call a current of electron wireless. So far you would have to study how the electromagnetic field propagates when you change the flux which is probably complicated but could give you some information. I do not see why it would be better than your usual antenna.

> What limits the distance between a moving particle and the solenoid on which A-B effect manifests itself? Shouldn't this distance, in principle, be infinite, as no classical fields are involved? What could be done to make it infinite?

Probably you can make the ring as large as you want, but at some point you will have to consider the following:

- Decoherence, quantum effects are hard to keep at large scales. You need that electrons move coherently between the two branches. The larger you make it the more likely that your electrons will find undesired interactions that will kill the coherence.
- Retardation effects. Not really a problem but supposing that the magnetic flux is located in a close region far from the ring, then for large distances a change in the magnetic flux will take some time (dictated by the speed of light) before the electrons "feel" the change in flux.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an ansewr, but one more question. Where could I find an explanation for a dummies what are the scalar and vector potentials and electromagnetic potentials? There seem to be lack of explanation for the beginners (even in wikipedia) and this is definitely out classical of school/university programs. No popular explanation whatsoever except mathematics. In the case of magnetic field we could talk about magnetic flux density which fade with the distance. If potentals aren't "real", then why do they suppose to fade with the distance and what could be there which fades? There is no field lines or any force or flux density, so why potentials manifest themselves only locally?

Comment: You should ask a question on the main site. Answers aren't for asking more questions ...